# Exported e4 RCP application can't be open because "damaged or incomplete" (OSX)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am relatively new to the e4 Java development. I have built an RCP-based application which runs when debugging or running through the Eclipse IDE (Neon). However, when I export the application for deployment, the exported launcher when clicked gives me an error ("You can't open the application [application name] because it may be damaged or incomplete"). I have also attempted to recreate the error by creating an empty RCP application and the same issue appears. In both of these cases, I have checked "The product includes native launcher artifacts".

Any idea of what the issue might be?

Product file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <?pde version="3.5"?>
>
> <product name="Pearl" uid="pearl" id="Information_Extraction_Workbench.product" application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" version="1.0.0.qualifier" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">
>
>
>    <configIni use="default">
>    </configIni>
>
>    <launcherArgs>
>       <programArgs>-clearPersistedState
>       </programArgs>
>       <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
>       </vmArgsMac>
>    </launcherArgs>
>
>    <windowImages/>
>
>
>    <launcher name="pearl">
>       <solaris/>
>       <win useIco="false">
>          <bmp/>
>       </win>
>    </launcher>
>
>
>    <vm>
>    </vm>
>
>
>    <plugins>
>       <plugin id="Information_Extraction_Workbench"/>
>       <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.servlet"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.commons.jxpath"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.hpux.ia64_32" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.help"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.tablecombo"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.aix.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.hpux.ia64_32" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.photon.qnx.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.cocoa" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.forms"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.themes"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
>    </plugins>
>
>
>    <preferencesInfo>
>       <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
>    </preferencesInfo>
>
>    <cssInfo>
>       <file path="/Information Extraction Workbench/css/default.css"/>
>    </cssInfo>
>
> </product>
> ```

This is the other application (minimal example) where error also duplicated

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <?pde version="3.5"?>
>
> <product name="com.example.e4.rcp.wizard" uid="blah" id="com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product" application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" version="1.0.0.qualifier" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">
>
>
>    <configIni use="default">
>    </configIni>
>
>    <launcherArgs>
>       <programArgs>-clearPersistedState
>       </programArgs>
>       <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
>       </vmArgsMac>
>    </launcherArgs>
>
>    <windowImages/>
>
>
>    <launcher name="rey">
>       <solaris/>
>       <win useIco="false">
>          <bmp/>
>       </win>
>    </launcher>
>
>
>    <vm>
>       <macos include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8</macos>
>    </vm>
>
>
>    <plugins>
>       <plugin id="com.example.e4.rcp.wizard"/>
>       <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.servlet"/>
>       <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.commons.jxpath"/>
>       <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.hpux.ia64_32" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension" fragment="true"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
>       <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
>    </plugins>
>
>
>    <preferencesInfo>
>       <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
>    </preferencesInfo>
>
>    <cssInfo>
>    </cssInfo>
>
> </product>
> ```

This is the error message that appeared after compilation that Eclipse wanted to send:

> > The following report will be sent to Eclipse:
>
> ------ STATUS
>   ------ pluginId            org.eclipse.pde.build pluginVersion       3.9.200.v20160204-0642 code                17 severity            4 message             HIDDEN fingerprint
>   307801a13ac4d782070cb3fca93512d0
>
> Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: HIDDEN   at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeFeatureFactory.parseBuildFeature(BuildTimeFeatureFactory.java:85)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeFeatureFactory.createFeature(BuildTimeFeatureFactory.java:50)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite.createFeature(BuildTimeSite.java:458)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.compatibility.FeatureReference.getFeature(FeatureReference.java:39)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite.resolveFeatureReferences(BuildTimeSite.java:316)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite.findFeature(BuildTimeSite.java:285)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite.findFeature(BuildTimeSite.java:277)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BuildScriptGenerator.generateFeatures(BuildScriptGenerator.java:249)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BuildScriptGenerator.generate(BuildScriptGenerator.java:127)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:255)
>      at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.ProductExportOperation.run(ProductExportOperation.java:105)
>      at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>
> ------ STATUS
>   ------ pluginId            org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse pluginVersion       1.2.100.v20160504-1450 code                17
>   severity            4 message             HIDDEN fingerprint
>   b9f4abf3b28ea9e6b7a2483f4ff27615
>
> ------ STATUS
>   ------ pluginId            org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse pluginVersion       1.2.100.v20160504-1450 code                17
>   severity            4 message             HIDDEN fingerprint
>   465298c82a36dba3f729743e02a61485
>
> ------ REPORT
>   ------ anonymousId         adc23f85-e164-4e7d-93ee-1d0b8861a2d7 name                Mona email               [email] comment              eclipseBuildId
>   4.6.0.I20160606-1100 eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_92-b14
>   osgiWs              cocoa osgiOs              MacOSX osgiOsVersion
>   10.11.5 osgiArch            x86_64 severity            UNKNOWN
>
> ------- BUNDLES
>   ------- name                org.eclipse.core.jobs version             3.8.0.v20160509-0411
>
> name                org.eclipse.pde.build version
>   3.9.200.v20160204-0642
>
> name                org.eclipse.pde version
>   3.12.0.v20160606-1100
>
> name                org.eclipse.pde.core version
>   3.11.0.v20160510-1223

Comment: This works fine for me on OS X 10.11.5 with Eclipse Neon. So what version of OS X is this? Edit your question and show us your .product file.

Comment: Hi gregg, I have El Capitan and edited my original question with the product file.

Comment: The main difference I see from what I have is the `<macos` entry in the `<vm>` section. Try leaving that out (Execution Environment on the Launching tab of the product editor).

Comment: even so, the first file doesn't have the macos entry in vm either. But regardless, i am getting the same issue. I did capture the error message that appeared during compilation.. i edited the original.

Comment: The log shows something wrong in the parsing of a feature.xml generated during the build. However I don't see anything that would say 'HIDDEN' for the error message.

Comment: the log says it has something to do with the require tab having at least one entry.. though I am not sure what exactly?  

Also, I used Eclipse Luna and noticed it successfully exported an executable that works, though I wish I could use the latest (Mars or Neon - both of which are giving the same issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, I gave up on the UI-based method to create a build. Instead I just caught up and learned the Tycho-based approach to create a deploy-able executable - even though it required some tweaking with the project configuration.

Good beginner tutorial:
https://simplejavablog.eu/2016/03/22/eclipse-rcp-part-1/